# 3-D Plotting with MATLAB for Galton's Skewness and Moor's Kurtosis

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, distribution

I know there are many plotting documents for Matlab online and I am pretty sure that it has been asked many times. I aplogize in advance for any inconvenience.

I am dealing with a new distribution and I need to draw 3D plot for different values of parameters (I can do it with Excel or any other programs, however, since my other graphs is drawn with MATLAB, and I need to put this 3D in Matlab, too, to publish it as an article). I calculated the result using MATLAB loops, however, plotting gives me the hardest time. I had no other choice but to ask for your assistance. I have these equations for different alphas and betas with a constant sigma and calculate Galton's Skewness and Moor's Kurtosis given with the last two equations.

```
median=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv(0.5,alpha));
q1=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((6/8),alpha));
q3=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((2/8),alpha));
q4=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((7/8),alpha));
q5=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((5/8),alpha));
q6=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((3/8),alpha));
q7=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta*gammaincinv((1/8),alpha));
galtonskewness=(q1-2*median+q3)/(q1-q3);
moorskurtosis=(q4-q5+q6-q7)/(q1-q3);
```

Let's assume that,

```
sigma=1
beta=[0.1 0.2 0.5 1 2 5];
alpha=[0.1 0.2 0.5 1 2 5];
```

I have used mesh(X,Y,Z) for the same range of alphas and betas with the same increment but I take the error "these values cannot be complex". I just want to draw something like the one below.
[image]

It must be something easy that I am missing out, but I do not understand where the mistake is. I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the above code for a 2D mesh of points for `alpha` and `beta` between 0.1 and 5 for both dimensions and I got results for both.

I suspect it's due to your `alpha` and `beta` declaration.  You are only providing a few points, and if you try to use `mesh`, it won't get good results.  Therefore, define a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of points for both `alpha` and `beta`, then **vectorize** your MATLAB code to produce the kurotsis and skewness curves.  Only under certain situations should you use `for` loops.  In general, you should avoid using them whenever possible.

How `meshgrid` works is that given a range of `X` and `Y` values, it will produce two (or three if you want 3D co-ordinates) arrays where each location in each array gives you the spatial co-ordinate at that particular location.  Therefore, if we did something like:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:3, 1:3);
```

This is what we get:

```
X =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


Y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```

Notice that in a 2D grid, for the top-left corner, `(x,y) = (1,1)`, and so for the corresponding location in `X`, we get 1 and `Y` we get 1.  If you do the same logic for any other position in the 2D grid, you simply look at the `X` and `Y` values in each array and it will tell you what the component is for each dimension.

As such, instead of looping through all possible points in your grid, generate them **all** using `meshgrid`, then vectorize the computation by calculating your values all at once rather than individually.  Once you do this, you have the right structure to be able to put this into `mesh`.

Therefore, try doing this instead:

```
%// Define meshgrid of points
[alpha,beta] = meshgrid(0.1:0.1:5, 0.1:0.1:5);

%// From your code
sigma = 1;

%// Calculate quantities - Notice that this is all vectorized
med=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv(0.5,alpha));
q1=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((6/8),alpha));
q3=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((2/8),alpha));
q4=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((7/8),alpha));
q5=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((5/8),alpha));
q6=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((3/8),alpha));
q7=sqrt(2*(sigma^2)*beta.*gammaincinv((1/8),alpha));
galtonskewness=(q1-2*med+q3)./(q1-q3);
moorskurtosis=(q4-q5+q6-q7)./(q1-q3);

%// Show our meshes
figure;
mesh(alpha, beta, galtonskewness);
figure;
mesh(alpha, beta, moorskurtosis);
```

---

Also take note that I renamed your `median` variable to `med`.  MATLAB has a function called [`median`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) and so you don't want to unintentionally shadow over this function with a variable of the same name.

This is what I get:

[image]

[image]

---

Take note that I'm not getting the plots that you have placed in your post.  It may be because I'm choosing the wrong variables to define the `mesh`, or perhaps your equations may be incorrect.  Double check what you know in theory to what you have here in code and try again.

This should hopefully give you enough to start with though!

Comment: Dear rayreng, thank you codially! To be perfectly honest, this was the same code I ran but got the error :/ I apologize to take your time. I will see that it will work or not. For the graphs, it's utterly okay that you cannot get the same results just because it does belong to another newly-generated distribution, which has different formulas for skewness and kurtosis.